# video.js: force control bar fade out

Tags: video.js

I followed some examples and implemented a stop button for the player on my page. I want the poster image to show up when I press 'stop' which I accomplish using `css` and `.show()`.

The only issue is that the control bar is still visible.

How do I force the controlbar to `fadeOut` similar to when the video is playing and the user is not moving the mouse, short of using `.fadeOut()`?

The problem is, if I use `fadeOut()`, I need to set the display property of css somewhere again to visible, otherwise i can't play the video again as the controlbar is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
.vjs-user-inactive {
  cursor: none;
}

or

.vjs-default-skin.vjs-user-inactive .vjs-control-bar {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
     -moz-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
      -ms-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
       -o-transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
          transition: visibility 1.5s, opacity 1.5s;
```

Comment: http://blog.videojs.com/post/57828375480/hiding-and-showing-video-player-controls

Comment: I saw that post, tried using the userActive(false) method, that didn't work. Thanks for your help, the CSS worked perfectly!

Comment: @JoeyD hurray! happy to help :)